# Display Random Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to randomize the loads of these divs for my homepage. I have some specific css that is making it difficult, otherwise I would have done one of the numerous suggestions for randomizing images. Thanks for your help!

```
<div class="banner-images">

<div class="feature" style="background-image: url(images/typewriter.png)">
    <img  class="hero-poster" src="images/typewriter.png" />

    <div class="hero-decoration">
        <div class="side-l"></div>
        <div class="arrow"><img alt="Hero-triangle" src="images/triangle.png" /></div>
        <div class="side-r"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="feature" style="background-image: url(images/printing.png)">
    <img  class="hero-poster" src="images/printing.png" />

    <div class="hero-decoration">
        <div class="side-l"></div>
        <div class="arrow"><img alt="Hero-triangle" src="images/triangle.png" /></div>
        <div class="side-r"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="feature" style="background-image: url(images/newspaper.png)">
    <img alt="Releaser" class="hero-poster" src="images/newspaper.png" />

    <div class="hero-decoration">
        <div class="side-l"></div>
        <div class="arrow"><img alt="Hero-triangle" src="images/triangle.png" /></div>
        <div class="side-r"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which `<divs>` are you specifically trying to randomise?

Comment: Are you trying to randomize the order or randomly display one of them? The title and question seem to be asking two different things.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you could do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    var visibleDiv = $('.feature')[rand];
    $(visibleDiv).show();
});
```

Generates a random number and then shows the element that coincides with that number.

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L33s18qp/)

Comment: perfection. great job!

Answer (score 0):

I used a random array shuffle function that I found online, because I didn't feel like writing one, but this is an okay way to do it. Basically, you'll take the `$('.feature')` array and shuffle it, then display those in that randomized order.

Looks something like:

```
$(function() {
    var shuffle = function(o){
        for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        return o;
    }
    var showArr = shuffle($('.feature'));
    $.each(showArr, function(k,v) { //key, value
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $(v).css('opacity', 1);
        },k*1000);
    });
});
```

Check it out and play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9bva204y/1/

Again, this is just a basic interpretation. You can play with it a little more and make it fancier and whatnot.